# Make arrayed object properly follow/fit curve

Tags: modifiers, path

For my arch viz projects I regularly need to place curbstones in various ways along streets, driveways, etc. Right now I have to place them all by hand and can only use the array (and curve) modifier for straight stretches or very wide bends. You can see in the first image below how Blender handles arrayed objects on shorter stretches and smaller bends (afaik).

So my question is if there's a way/modifier/addon/etc for blender to handle this kind of operation smarter. I know increasing the geometry of the curbstone partly solves this, but it still results in weird shapes and corners etc because Blender insists on using the whole model (see image 2). Ideally I want to be able to draw 1 continuous path and then have blender "logically" place and cut the curbstones along it.

Thanks!

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]